# Core dump analysis using gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin, segmentation-fault

I have a couple of questions regarding core dumps. I have gdb on Windows, using Cygwin.

1. What is the location of core dump file? Is it a.exe.stackdump file? (This is the only file that generated after crash) I read on other forums that the core dump file is named "core". But I don't see any file with name "core".
2. What is the command for opening and understanding core dump file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You need to configure Cygwin to produce core dumps by including

   `error_start=x:\path\to\dumper.exe` 
   in your `CYGWIN` environment variable (see [here](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html) in section "dumper" for more information). If you didn't do this, you will only get a stacktrace -- which may also help you in diagnosing the problem, though.
2. Start gdb as follows to attach it to a core dump file:

   `gdb myexecutable --core=mycorefile` 
   You can now use the usual gdb commands to print a stacktrace, examine the values of variables, and so on.

Comment: How to modify cygwin environment variable?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable. If you're using Cygwin, I would strongly recommend that you read up on some Unix basics -- you're going to need them.

Comment: Actually I know the concept of environment variable. I understood what u r saying, setting environment variable named "error_start". I am asking where should I define the new environment variable? at the same place (my computer->properties->...) ?

Comment: That's an option -- but a better place is probably in cygwin.bat, since the variable is specific to Cygwin. Or, for testing, just set the variable from the bash shell (using the `export` command) just before you run the executable you're testing.

Comment: I did this in cygwin shell before running my executable. "export error_start=/c/cygwin/bin/dumper.exe". Still it did not generate the core file.

Comment: Try `CYGWIN=error_start=c:\cygwin\bin\dumper.exe`. See also http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg77667.html for more advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Got it finally by adding "set CYGWIN=error_start=c:\cygwin\bin\dumper.exe"

Comment: When using Bash and `export`, you need to quote the backslashes: `export CYGWIN='error_start=C:\Opt\Cygwin\bin\dumper.exe'`

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, cygwin creates `a.exe.stackdump` files by default. You need to configure it to create `core`s as well (Martin's answer covers that).
2. A simple tutorial on core dump debugging can be found [here](http://bloggerdigest.blogspot.com/2006/09/gnu-gdb-core-dump-debugging.html)